# CSS centering stuff

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: url('background.jpg')
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: white;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 4px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', ;
  border: 6px solid black;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>hhchh</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="N:\Desktop\Javascript\JS.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="N:\Desktop\Javascript\appStyle.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>text and stuff</h2>
    <p>button text</p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to center something and it's not working.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0wd3.png)

[This is what I've been able to do so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaR9O.jpg) but the button width is 100%, I want it to be like 100px

**Things that I tried -**

1)

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

2) Make it like a table, If I have to do it like this, then I think I'm better off with bootstrap.

3) Using position relative and making it look like center.

4)

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap the button within a div and make the div have `text-align:center`. like so:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <button>Button Text</button>
</div>
```

That way, you don't have to know (or care) exactly how wide the button will be.

here's a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/cjc50q1g/

**update:** now that you've posted your code, I see that you could just add `margin: 0 auto` to your "button" which is really a paragraph (see below). **However**, I'm not a fan of putting absolute widths on things for responsive reasons. If it were me, I'd replace the `<p>` with an inline element (`<button>`, `<a>`, `<span>`, etc.) and wrap it in a `<div>` with `text-align:center;` like I explained above.

```css
body {
  background: url('background.jpg')
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: white;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 4px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', ;
  border: 6px solid black;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>hhchh</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="N:\Desktop\Javascript\JS.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="N:\Desktop\Javascript\appStyle.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>text and stuff</h2>
    <p>button text</p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-top: -50px;
```